# How can I add a running integer to my current time in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have a SQLite DB where in the field Messdatum there is only the date as TEXT. Now I would like
to concat a random time to the field so that the Messdatum results in ISO format with time.
How can I update my SQL DB with one sql command?

My Select to test is:
    SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Messdatum) ||' ' || strftime('%H:%M:%S', CURRENT_TIME)from lipo

but there always the same TIme.
THanks

Comment: IN the meantime I have exported the SQL content to Excel and merged there a random time to the date and reimported it to SQLite

Comment: What do you mean with "random"?

Comment: well I do not know the acutal time of the dates, so I would like to add a random time to the date so that it becomes a ISO timestamp in TEXT format

Comment: I could tell you to use `datetime(Messdatum, '+' || (abs(random()) % 86400) || ' seconds')`, but this is obviously not what you want (it's certainly not guaranteed to be unique).

Comment: No it's not. Are duplicate values allowed? If yes, why not simply use `'+42 seconds'` instead?

Comment: @CL well duplicate are not for the same date allowed. But if the date is different the time could be the same. But I would like to run it also under Mysql. But there I got an error: [SQL] update lipo set Messdatum =datetime(Messdatum, '+' || (abs(random()) % 86400) || ' seconds')  where Messdatum like '%00:00:00%' ;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Messdatum, '+' || (abs(random()) % 86400) || ' seconds')  where Messdatum like ' at line 1

Comment: the reason could be: Messdatum is in MySQL a datetime and in SQLite a TEXT type. How can I convert the generated String in a datetime for MySQL?

Comment: I got it: select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lipo.Messdatum) + (abs(rand()*1000000) % 86400),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')  from lipo where Messdatum like '%00:00:00%' ;

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted random times, you could just add a random number of seconds (86400 is the number of seconds in a day):

```
SELECT datetime(Messdatum, '+' || (abs(random()) % 86400) || ' seconds')
FROM lipo
```

However, this does **not** guarantee that the values are unique for each day.

To get unique values, you could use the internal [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), but this works only if the first and that last row for each day are less than 86400 rows apart, i.e., this can break if you insert additional rows for a specific day much later:

```
SELECT datetime(Messdatum, '+' || (rowid % 86400) || ' seconds')
FROM lipo
```

The most reliable (but slowest) way would be to count how many previous rows there are with the same date:

```
SELECT datetime(Messdatum, '+' || (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                   FROM lipo AS L2
                                   WHERE L2.Messdatum = lipo.Messdatum
                                     AND L2.rowid < lipo.rowid
                                  ) || ' seconds')
FROM lipo
```